# Adding constraints to imageview in collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints

I'm trying to collectionViewCell image to have full width and then the height equal to the image, so it is proportionally, i've created below constraints, but nothing seem to happen?

```
class BrowseCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mainImageView:UIImageView?


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect())



        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        var viewBindingsDict: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        viewBindingsDict.setValue(mainImageView, forKey: "MainImageView")
        mainImageView?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[MainImageView(==width)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]))
        mainImageView?.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[MainImageView(==height)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: viewBindingsDict as [NSObject : AnyObject]))









    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you declare imageView as `@IBOutlet`, it probably created in storyboard, therefore you need initialize cell in `init(coder: NSCoder)` function.
2. You can't add constraints in `init(coder: NSCoder)` to `@IBOutlet` views, because they don't exist at this point. This can be done in `updateConstraints()`, like follows:

   ```
   override func updateConstraints()
   {
       mainImageView.removeConstraints(mainImageView.constraints())
       mainImageView.addConstraints(...)
       super.updateConstraints()
   }
   ```

I think it would be better to add constraints in storyboard and change the size of cell depending on image properties in `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize` delegate method.